# PowerShell - Send HTML file as Body of Email

Tags: powershell

I am sorry for interrupting your daily work, but I need some help with the script below.
The HTML report works fine, but it collects the data and puts them as HTML.  The problem is when I sent the HTML, it sends it as an attachment, not as Body.
I get the following error message

````
Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:20 char:134
+ ... edtronic.com -Subject "Folder Delition" -Body $CoryReportHtml -BodyAs ...```
````

Could someone check what I am doing wrong?

```
#Time when the email is sent
$emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

#Locate Folders older than 30 days
$CoryReportHtml += Get-ChildItem "\\Server01\XFER\Cory" -Directory | 
    Sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
        <h2>Folders older than 30 days</h2> 
        <body>
            Folders were removed on - $emailTime
            <br></br>
            Location: \\Server01\XFER\Cory
        <body> 
        <br></br>" |
    Out-File "C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryHtmlReport.html"


Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.company.com -to cubam1@company.com -from cubam1@company.com -Subject "Folder Delition" -Body $CoryReportHtml -BodyAsHtml = $true -Attachments "C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryHtmlReport.html"
```

Comment: Take out the `= $true` after `-BodyAsHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the html as attachment AND as the body try using Tee-Object  to also send the output to file as well as your $CoryReportHtml variable.

Additionally, I don't see $header defined anywhere so remove it from your ConvertTo-Html.  I think your Precontent also need to be placed in a here string @" "

```
#Time when the email is sent
$emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

#Locate Folders older than 30 days
$CoryReportHtml = Get-ChildItem '\\Server01\XFER\Cory' -Directory |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime |
    ConvertTo-Html -PreContent @"
        <h2>Folders older than 30 days</h2>
        <div>
            Folders were removed on - $emailTime
            <br></br>
            Location: \\Server01\XFER\Cory
        </div>
        <br></br>
"@ | Tee-Object -FilePath 'C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryHtmlReport.html' | Out-String

$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer = 'mail.company.com'
    to         = 'cubam1@company.com'
    from       = 'cubam1@company.com'
    Subject    = 'Folder Delition'
    Body       = $CoryReportHtml
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Attachments = 'C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryHtmlReport.html'
}

Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Comment: Thank you so much,
I am getting the following now
```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:18 char:134
+ ... edtronic.com -Subject "Folder Delition" -Body $CoryReportHtml -BodyAs ...
```

Comment: @Miguel Change `... | Tee-Object -FilePath ....` to `... | Tee-Object -FilePath .... | Out-String`.

Comment: @BaconBits thanks.  Updated my answer with your correction.  I had forgotten that ConvertTo-Html outputs an array and that -Body only will accept a string...

Answer (score 1):

It is working now
I added
$CoryReportHtml = $CoryReportHtml -join ""
And it was able to send as HTML :D
Thank you!

Comment: Ah, right.  Good find!  You should change your accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is being sent as an attachment due to the flag `-Attachments`.
What i would do is remove this bit of code
`| Out-File "C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryHtmlReport.html"`
and just pass the `$CoryReportHtml` variable as body and try it out that way

Comment: if you print the variable before trying to send what does it show? is it empty or do you get well structured html